# How do you prevent Guice from injecting a class not bound in the Module?

Tags: java, guice

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

public class GuiceDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GuiceDemo().run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new EmptyModule());
        DemoInstance demoInstance = injector.getInstance(DemoInstance.class);
        assert(demoInstance.demoUnbound == null);
    }

    public static class EmptyModule extends AbstractModule
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure()
        {
        }
    }

    public static class DemoInstance
    {
        public final DemoUnbound demoUnbound;

        @Inject
        public DemoInstance(DemoUnbound demoUnbound)
        {
            this.demoUnbound = demoUnbound;
        }
    }

    public static class DemoUnbound
    {
    }
}
```

Can I prevent Guice from providing an instance of DemoUnbound to the constructor of DemoInstance?

In essence I am looking for a way to run Guice in a totally explicit binding mode where injecting an unbound class is an error.

How do you make it an error to Guice inject a class not bound in the Module?

Comment: @johncarl thank you for the syntax fix.  I didn't like my original code as it was doing the demo from the constructor which is ugly :)  I should have checked the code before posting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use an interface here instead of a concrete class for DemoUnbound, Guice will throw an exception because it cannot find a suitable class to inject:

```
public class GuiceDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GuiceDemo().run();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new EmptyModule());
        DemoInstance demoInstance = injector.getInstance(DemoInstance.class);
        assert(demoInstance.demoUnbound == null);
    }

    public static class EmptyModule extends AbstractModule
    {
        @Override
        protected void configure()
        {
        }
    }

    public static class DemoInstance
    {
        public final DemoUnbound demoUnbound;

        @Inject
        public DemoInstance(DemoUnbound demoUnbound)
        {
            this.demoUnbound = demoUnbound;
        }
    }

    public interface DemoUnbound
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: A valid solution.  I should have clarified my intent.  The problem is I want to prevent programmers from injecting public classes that already exist.  Beyond compiler boundaries I still can't see a solution to this.  I suppose the solution is code review :S

Comment: I think I need a little clarification.  What do you mean by:  "I want to prevent programmers from injecting public classes that already exist"

Comment: I want to make it so that the code I provide above doesn't work.  I would like it so that I was forced to have "bind(DemoInstance.class, DemoInstance.class)" to make it work.  Does Guice support this?  Basically this has been identified as a deadly flaw and is leading to a possible wholesale removal of Guice from our code.  We want to explicitly control exactly the types that can be injected.

Comment: Honestly this sounds like a strange request.  Why is this a deadly flaw?  What is preventing devs from just executing this: DemoInstance instance = new DemoInstance(new DemoUnbound()) ?

Comment: I agree with you.  I will make the case that a code review can easily pick up inappropriate constructor parameters. DI frameworks are a hard sell where I am unfortunately and it seems that people can be inventive in arguing against them :)

Answer (score 13):

Try putting `binder().requireExplicitBindings();` in your Module. It won't keep you from injecting concrete classes, but it will require a module to include `bind(DemoUnbound.class);` to make it more obvious.

[Read the Binder docs](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.2.3/javadoc/com/google/inject/Binder.html#requireExplicitBindings--) for more information.

Comment: This sounds like it fits the bill... I was unaware of this configuration.